# How does this set look like?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have trouble to understand the following set:

$M_2 = \{ 1 \le \|x\|_2 \lt 2 \} \cup \{ \vec{O} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $

On the left side there are scalars and on the right side there is the null vector. Can we have sets with elements of different dimension?

Comment: Perhaps it is $M_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1\leq \|x\|_2 < 2\}\cup \{0\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Prahlad mentioned in the comments, the left set is really shorthand for $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 1\leq\| x\|_2<2\}$ which can be read as *the set of vectors in the plane such that their $2$-norm is less than $2$ and great than or equal to $1$*, and so it really is a set of vectors (which is of course just a set of points in the plane).

In terms of the geometry of the set $M_2$, you can view it as the union of an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29) determined by the requisite radii and only containing its 'inner boundary circle' and not the outer, together with the point at the center of the annulus.

Comment: Thanks, that way it makes sense. Would have been nice, when the notation had been introduced by my lecturer..

Comment: Sometimes in mathematics, if there is a property $P$ which takes values in a set $X$, we will often write $\{P(x)\}\subset X$ to mean the set of points $x$ in $X$ which satisfy the property $P$. It's quite common, but I agree somewhat ambiguous out of context.

Answer (score 2):

if we add vector arrows it becomes more clear;
$$M_2=\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1\leq \|\vec{x} \|_2 < 2 \} \cup \vec{O}$$

Comment: The TeX \vec{x} makes it look a little nicer.